# which build tool should be used for continuous integration for pl/sql packages

Tags: oracle, jenkins, plsql, deployment, continuous-integration

We want to do continuous integration of the pl/sql packages. Jenkins will be used as a CI tool. How do i build the plsql code in jenkins? for eg: I use maven build for the java code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be, to run your `pl/sql`-script-files with `sqlPlus`.

```
c:\>sqlplus uesr/pw@db @"c:\plsqlScript.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm look for what should be the best way to build a CI with PL/SQL code.

You can follow this [tips to help pl/sql developers get started with ci/cd](https://learncodeshare.net/2018/04/30/tips-to-help-pl-sql-developers-get-started-with-ci-cd/) article written by [Blaine Carter](https://github.com/OsBlaineOra)